# Fix Subreport Expression Class in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

Lately I had a problem with printing a master-detail report using JavaBeans datasource (I didn't use MySQL datasource for some reasons).

I can not change the expression class of subreport to java.util.List (I had made the subreport.jrxml and mainreport.jrxml). But as you see in the picture below, that class expression is not exist in my subreport properties.

[image: java.util.List not found here]

Then I tried to write it manually. I added these codes to my XML file.

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="100"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{orderDetails})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression class="java.util.List"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "sub_main_report.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Now it's showing another error like this.
[image: another error]

Sorry if I've explained it bad. Have anyone here got the same problem with me?

Note: My iReport version is 4.0.1 with JDK 1.7 running in Linux Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit environment.

Comment: One *subreport* element is only for one report. The `subreportExpression ` can't take a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The`subreportExpression` can only be used with a few classes, such as `java.lang.String`.  It cannot be `java.util.List`.  Your second error message shows the list of accepted classes.

**Update**

You have to understand that the `subreportExpression` tells the system how to load the sub-report.  There can only be one value.  So the expression cannot be an `java.util.List`.  If you have multiple sub-reports, you have to have multiple elements of `subreport`, each with its own `subreportExpression`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. Sorry for slow respond, I haven't checked my email for a long time.

I realized that I have to use JRBeanDataSource and pass the list type in the constructor as my datasource for the subreport element. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've accepted your answer. But I need min. 15 rep to upvote it